# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'IntegerChoices'

Tags: python, django-models

I have a problem that I cannot solve, when starting the server, it gives an error:

> class CritLevel (models.IntegerChoices): AttributeError: module
> 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'IntegerChoices'

My code in the model:

```
import uuid

from common.models import CommonPermissionSet

from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

from django.db import models

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from. import managers

class CritLevel (models.IntegerChoices):
     LOW = 1, _ ('Low')
     MEDIUM = 2, _ ('Medium')
     HIGH = 3, _ ('High')

class TypeElHw (models.IntegerChoices):
     EL = 1, _ ('Electrical Energy')
     HW = 2, _ ('Heat energy')

class OrganizationType (models.IntegerChoices):
     EPO = 1, _ ('EPO')
     ESO = 2, _ ('ESO')
```

Comment: What version of Django do you use?

Comment: The problem was this, I was using django 2.2.12. Thanks!